# detecting geometric shapes in UML, flowcharts

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I am looking for ways to automatically image-process a state-machine diagram (eg. Finite State Machine or see a sample at http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/images/TrafficLight.gif) and turn it into a state-transition table.  I am told that this is a solved problem -- in that there are multiple automatic image processing solutions out there that already process diagrams and turn them into some internal notation. Is this true? Also, are there similar solutions for flow charts or any other UML diagrams (like message sequence charts) also?

FYI, for image processing I am using OpenCV on windows. For text recognition (i.e. OCR), I have found Tessract useful. Before finding my own mechanism to automatically processing state-machines, I wish to know if this is a solved problem.